# Dynamic XML response based on the XML input

Tags: java, xml, xslt, soap

We are building a web service which takes an XML input and provides and XML response based on the input. The input XML contains the XML structure with empty value, the empty values will be replaced by the actual value based on the data in the database. The user can reduce the number of nodes requested in the input XML, if they do not want all the details.

Sample Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML>
    <RequestHeader>
        <id>123</id>
    </RequestHeader>
    <RequestedElement>
        <ABC>
            <DEF>
                <GHI />
                <JKL>
                    <MNO />
                </JKL>
            </DEF>
        </ABC>
    </RequestedElement>
</XML>
```

Sample Response

```
<XML>
    <ABC>
        <DEF>
            <GHI>Value1</GHI>
            <JKL>
                <MNO>Value2</MNO>
            </JKL>
        </DEF>
    </ABC>
</XML>
```

The way I have implemented now, is to having a mapping of the XML nodes to the table names and column names, and then use reflection to retrieve the data from the database and generate the XML. However using reflection is slowing down the whole process.

The other option which I can think of is to get rid of reflection and to create the XML with all the nodes, and then use XSLT to generate the final XML with only the requested nodes. Is this possible to do so with XSLT?

Is there any better option to do the same which can increase the performance and get the desired results?

Comment: Give a shot to `GraphQL`

Answer (score 0):

> We are building a web service which takes an XML input and provides
>   and XML response based on the input. The input XML contains the XML
>   structure with empty value, the empty values will be replaced by the
>   actual value based on the data in the database. The user can reduce
>   the number of nodes requested in the input XML, if they do not want
>   all the details

One way to do this is to invoke the chosen XSLT processor (how to do this differs from one XSLT processor to another -- read the documentation) passing to it global transformation parameters, whose names are the names of the elements that should receive the corresponding values.

In the transformation below the values of the parameters are hardcoded, but in the real implementation these must be provided by the invoker -- so in the XSLT code they will look like this:

```
 <xsl:param name="GHI"/>
 <xsl:param name="MNO"/>
```

**Here is the complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="GHI">Value1</xsl:param>
 <xsl:param name="MNO">Value2</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RequestHeader"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(node()) and name() = document('')/*/xsl:param/@name]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/xsl:param[@name = name(current())]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<XML>
    <RequestHeader>
        <id>123</id>
    </RequestHeader>
    <RequestedElement>
        <ABC>
            <DEF>
                <GHI />
                <JKL>
                    <MNO />
                </JKL>
            </DEF>
        </ABC>
    </RequestedElement>
</XML>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<XML>
   <RequestedElement>
      <ABC>
         <DEF>
            <GHI>Value1</GHI>
            <JKL>
               <MNO>Value2</MNO>
            </JKL>
         </DEF>
      </ABC>
   </RequestedElement>
</XML>
```